# Execute all cases in switch statement - specific issue

Tags: c++

How to execute all cases in switch statement without duplicating existing in big "all-in-one" case ?

For e.g.

```
switch(obj.nObjType)
{
case eElephant:
...
break;
case eFoo:
...
break;
case eSeptember:
...
break;
default:
return;
}
```

I want force executing code for all 3 cases (`eElephant, eFoo, eSeptember`) like there is no `break;`, for example in case of `nObjType = eAllTypes` .

Comment: You can extract that code to a functions:
`void processElephant(); void processFoo(); void processSeptember()`
`case eElephant: processElephant(); break; case eFoo: processFoo(); break; default: processElephant(); processFoo(); break;`

Comment: @NirMH There is almost always another way. And the question which one is the best depends very much on the environment (about which we know nothing here).

Comment: So remove the `break.` What's the question? And what's the point? If you want to execute all the code, why have a `switch` statement at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use `if` statements:

```
if (obj.nObjType == eElephant || obj.nObjType == eAllTypes)
{
    // Elephant code
}

if (obj.nObjType == eFoo || obj.nObjType == eAllTypes)
{
    // Foo code
}

// etc.
```

Comment: This solution doesn't handle the case when the value of `obj.nObjType` isn't on the enumerator-list, like `default` keyword does in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 6):

You can't just ignore a break. Rather, restructure your code.

```
switch(obj.nObjType) {
  case eElephant:
    pokeElephant();
    break;
  case eFoo:
    barTheFoo();
    break;
  case eSeptember:
    rememberSeptember();
    break;
  case eAllTypes:
    pokeElephant();
    barTheFoo();
    rememberSeptember();
    break;
  default:
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think you can ignore it if you set it into a 'if (!all) break' that would be totally ugly!

Comment: Ahh, I was one second late posting something very similar :-). I'd like to add that it is always good to avoid duplicated code and the key to that is extracting methods (as Amadan shows here).

Comment: @Surt: Oh. Yes, indeed. You could write code that would ignore break, as you say; but that is kind of horrible. (Not that I haven't ever written horrible code, but why give people ideas? We all write horrible code even without any help :P )

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26115931/4022608) is how it should be done.
However:

> I can see, it's hard to find as right solution without generating lots
>   of code lines. Thanks @TobiMcNamobi, but in my switch there is about
>   200 of cases, so creating a function for each case is not a good idea.
>   I think, the best can be (unfortunately) duplicating all cases in a
>   big one. Because, I suppose, if else is much less efficient then
>   switch statement ?

With this many cases (what on earth are you working on?) even extracting methods leaves you with 200 extra function calls in the body of your switch statement. This could get harder to maintain quickly.

In *this* case, I would do the following:

```
switch(enum_variable)
{
  case e_all:

  case e_1:
    e_1_function();
    if(enum_variable != e_all){break;}   //**

  case e_2:
    e_2_function();
    if(enum_variable != e_all){break;}   //**

  //...

  default:
    break;
}
```

The lines marked `//**` will break when not doing all cases.  It is quick to implement (can be done with a search and replace of `break;` which speeds things up for you) and does what you want.
With that said, it's still a pretty terrible way of doing it, but exceptions do sometimes have to be made.

I do however recommend that you *do not* turn to this as a style to use in the future.  You may find that you can do better by re-thinking the workflow of your project, as this will probably allow you to simplify and improve. Of course, we don't know what you are working on, so I can't offer more advice.

Comment: Agreed. I'd like to add the following: 1. "generating lots of code lines" isn't necessarily bad as long as those lines reflect the complexity of what the code ought to do. 2. Without further knowledge I still find generating a function for each case a good idea (believe me, ChestNoot: I'm wrestling with similar code myself). At least it is better than duplication. And on the other hand (as Baldrickk pointed out so clear and true) it might not be applicable due to project / time constraints. As an intermediate (!) solution Baldrickks answer is great. 3. I strongly recommend to do unit testing.

Comment: Yes, break it out into functions, don't have code in the switch statement (mixing different levels of abstraction).  What I was trying to avoid was the case where you miss one of the functions in the `e_all` case, which is suprisingly easy to do with 200 odd functions to copy in.  Definitely not a _good_ solution, just intermediate as you said, hence the link to Amadam's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your switch statement in a function, and make your `obj` have a *list* of flags rather than a flag, you can call the function with the switch statement for each  flag in the list. Pseudo:

```
void dostuff(flag)
    switch(flag) {
        // ...
    }
}

for (auto flag in obj.flags) {
    dostuff(flag)
}
```